# How do you create Magento translation strings including variable contents?

Tags: php, magento, internationalization

In Magento, performing a translation in modules involves invoking a helper and calling its translation function, E.G.

```
Mage::helper("core")->__("This is a string to translate");
```

However, I haven't found any resources online regarding translating strings that contain variables. From past experience, I know that this is usually handled by using a token inside the string, with token replacements defined using additional arguments.

For example, GNU gettext's manual recommends using format strings for translation:

```
sprintf (gettext ("Hello %s!"), username ());
```

While Yii Framework has a similar, but subtly different format:

```
Yii::t("default", "Hello {username}!", array("username"=>username()));
```

From a quick grep of Magento's core files, it looks like Magento uses C-style format strings, for example in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Api_User_Edit::getHeaderText the following can be found:

```
return Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__("Edit User '%s'", $this->escapeHtml(Mage::registry('api_user')->getUsername()));
```

But I would like further confirmation or advice since online documentation is quite sparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento uses following syntax for translation:

```
Mage::helper('catalog')->__("This is %s text %s", "First String", "Second String");
```

As suggested by Markus Harrison, I am adding these documentation for format strings:

[Formatting link 1](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html)

[Formatting link 2 - wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholder_specification)

Comment: For the sake of completeness it's probably worth including a link to some documentation on format strings, such as [this tutorial for format strings](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html), [the Wikipedia page for printf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholder_specification) or [a reference page for the printf function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).